# How to insert query filter based on count result in redash

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, having-clause, redash

it is a simple question I believe, but as I'm not familiar with redash it seems hard.

I have a query in redash,

```
SELECT si.variant_id,
       v.sku,
       COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN a.viewable_type = 'Spree::Variant' THEN a.id
             END) AS photo
FROM spree_stock_items si
LEFT JOIN spree_stock_locations sl ON sl.id = si.stock_location_id
LEFT JOIN spree_assets a ON si.variant_id = a.viewable_id
LEFT JOIN spree_variants v ON v.id = si.variant_id
WHERE-- viewable_type = 'Spree::Variant'
sl.name='{{store_location}}'
  AND si.deleted_at IS NULL
  AND sl.country_id = '2'
GROUP BY 1,
         2
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT 200000
```

which give results like this:
[image]

as of now, I can filter the results on the `store location`. but now I want to add `query filter` based on the column `photo`. How can I do it? basically I want to filter the result in redash dashboard by the `store location` and the count in `photo` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause - but it requires repeating the aggregate expression. For example:

```
SELECT si.variant_id,
       v.sku,
       COUNT(a.id) FILTER(WHERE a.viewable_type = 'Spree::Variant') AS photo
FROM spree_stock_items si
LEFT JOIN spree_stock_locations sl ON sl.id = si.stock_location_id
LEFT JOIN spree_assets a ON si.variant_id = a.viewable_id
LEFT JOIN spree_variants v ON v.id = si.variant_id
WHERE-- viewable_type = 'Spree::Variant'
    sl.name='{{store_location}}'
    AND si.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND sl.country_id = '2'
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING COUNT(a.id) FILTER(WHERE a.viewable_type = 'Spree::Variant') > 1
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT 200000
```

Note that I rewrote the `count()` to use the standard `filter` clause, which makes the syntax neater.

Alternatively, you can use a subquery, and a `WHERE` clause in the outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT si.variant_id,
           v.sku,
           COUNT(a.id) FILTER(WHERE a.viewable_type = 'Spree::Variant') AS photo
    FROM spree_stock_items si
    LEFT JOIN spree_stock_locations sl ON sl.id = si.stock_location_id
    LEFT JOIN spree_assets a ON si.variant_id = a.viewable_id
    LEFT JOIN spree_variants v ON v.id = si.variant_id
    WHERE-- viewable_type = 'Spree::Variant'
    sl.name='{{store_location}}'
      AND si.deleted_at IS NULL
      AND sl.country_id = '2'
    GROUP BY 1, 2
) t
WHERE photo > 1
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT 200000
```

Comment: what if I want to use the parameter function in redash? how should I add the query parameter based on the count result?

Comment: @NurAtiqah: sure, you can replace the `1` at the end of the `HAVING` clause (or the outer `WHERE` clause in the second query) with the parameter.